# Visual Studio 2008 formats asp tags to lowercase

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, formatting, webforms

Recently, my Visual Studio 2008(with Resharper 4.5) has started to reformat asp tags into lowercase.

Example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rp">
```

becomes

```
<asp:repeater runat="server" id="rp">
```

and I can't find a way to make it not do this. I use Ctrl-k Ctrl-d to reformat.

I've tried resetting the Visual Studio settings, turning off Resharper. Nothing seems to bite.

I did delete a huge Reflected something folder in my Documents and Settings folder last week, could this be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same (or very similar) issue.

I also deleted some (but not all) files in the folder

```
C:\Documents and Settings[username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

The reason I did this is because I'm subject to a frankly daft limit on the size of my (Windows XP) roaming profile :-(

After I did this VS intellisense and document auto-formatting started behaving as if it didn't know what the <asp: tags were and treated all the html as plain html (formatted tag names and attributes in lowercase).

I found [this blog post](http://timvasil.com/blog14/post/2007/11/Fix-for-%27asp%27-is-an-unrecognized-tag-prefix.aspx) by Tim Vasil which pointed me to the solution.

Here's what I did to fix this:

1. Deleted all files in C:\Documents
   and Settings[username]\Application
   Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas
2. Deleted all files in
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
   ASP.NET Files
3. Deleted the .suo User Option file (the file has the same name as the solution file with .suo in place of .sln)

(Note: VS eventually regenerates the various files in it's own time...)

Answer (score 4):

Go to Tools | Options...

Expand: Text Editor - HTML

Select the "Format" node, and see what settings you have for "Capitalization" of "Server tag" and "Server attributes - I think the default is now "Lowercase" - try setting that to "Assmebly definition" instead.

More information on these options can be found here:

> [Format, HTML, Text Editor, Options Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s960scy.aspx)

Comment: The problem is not that VS isn't obeying it's formatting settings - the problem is that VS thinks that the ASP.NET control declarations are plain generic html.. I've posted an answer that fixed this for me...

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. I put back that 650MB big folder in C:\Documents and Settings\My User Id\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0 and everything seems to be back to normal.

Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: I had the same issue. I deleted some, but not all of the files in the folder C:\Documents and Settings\\[username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas. After I did this VS intellisense and document aut-formatting started behaving as if it didn't know what the <asp: tags were and treated all the html as plain html (formatted tag names and attreibutes in lowercase).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about a permanent fix, but what you can do is select the troublesome coding then hit CTRL+K followed by CTRL+F, so in order..

```
CTRL + K, F
```

This will auto format the coding (and make it the proper case).
If this doesn't work then it might be an auto-format issue/setting

Comment: It was ctrl-k-f that made the html all-lower case.