# Format Document in Visual Studio 2010 asp tags format to lowercase

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a similar problem of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037288/visual-studio-2008-formats-asp-tags-to-lowercase).

When I try to use a shortcut CTRL + K, CTRL + D in a asp.net file (*.aspx) in order to format the document, all the document is reformated to lowercase.

I tried the solution exposed for visual stuio 2008 but doesn't work.

I've tried resetting the Visual Studio settings, turning off Resharper (v6.1). Nothing seems to bite.

Some ideas to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Visual Studio 2012, I changed my Formatting settings in Tools, Options.

Go to Text Editor, HTML, Formatting. Try the settings under Capitalization.

This problem is also discussed here [Visual Studio 2008 formats asp tags to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037288/visual-studio-2008-formats-asp-tags-to-lowercase)