# Visual Studio 2013 Format Document converts attributes to lowercase in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

For some odd reason, Visual Studio 2013 keeps converting the following line of code:

```
<input type="button" value="@T("Checkout.ShipToThisAddress")" class="button-1 select-shipping-address-button" onclick=" setLocation('@Url.RouteUrl("CheckoutSelectShippingAddress", new {addressid = item.Id})') " />
```

To this:

```
<input type="button" value="@T("Checkout.ShipToThisAddress")" class="btn-default-1 pull-right" onclick=" setlocation('@url.routeurl("checkoutselectshippingaddress", new { addressid = item.id })') " />
```

Note that tag attribute names as well as content are lower case. Also, Visual Studio complains that the line is missing a double-quote only in the editor. Here's the generated output:

```
<input type="button" value="Bill to this address" class="btn-default-1 pull-right" onclick="setLocation(' /checkout/selectbillingaddress?addressid=10856 ') ">
```

I tried to use the following suggestions, but it applies only to ASP not MVC pages. I couldn't find an MVC option in the Text Editor options in VS 2013.

[Format Document in Visual Studio 2010 asp tags format to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408640/format-document-in-visual-studio-2010-asp-tags-format-to-lowercase)

Comment: It looks like a bug in VS, it thinks your Razor syntax is part of the HTML rather than distinct. I suggest filing this on MS Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps the problem is related to the convoluted javascript? Checkout my edits.

Comment: Please also post the **rendered HTML** as well.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? Post it to your question.

Comment: I've seen this with various pieces of JavaScript. My recommendation is first, Separate JS and markup. (Bind in a document ready even and stop using `on*` attributes). If that's not practical, try storing your JS in a variable beforehand so it's simply `onclick="@myvar"`.

Comment: Just added the rendered code output to look at. I just get a javascript error that the setlocation is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in Tools > Options > Text Editor.

Within the HTML (Web Forms) section, select 'Formatting' and you can set 'Capitalization' for various items including 'Client attributes'

It appears to default to 'Lowercase' but you can change it to 'As entered'.

Comment: After some more testing it appears that the above solution doesn't work, even though it seems like it should fix this issue!  This looks like a defect in VS2013.  Note that VS2015 doesn't display this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> value= "@Html.Raw(Checkout.ShipToThisAddress)"