# How to prevent asp.net to make lowercase my custom attribute I placed in a server control

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page and controls on it. For the purpose consuming it at client side javascript I would like to place attributes for my elements. I would like to do it all in the markup, not in code behind. It seems the placed attributes will be all lowercased at client side.

For example:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="anyButton" runat="server" confirmationMessage='any message'...
```

will be rendered at client side as:

```
<a confirmationmessage='any message'...
```

Consequently I must use this casing all my javascript code. Not a big issue, but quite disturbing if you like strict naming conventions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See @Zhaph - Ben Duguid's answer in [Visual Studio 2008 formats asp tags to lowercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037288/visual-studio-2008-formats-asp-tags-to-lowercase).

Comment: Please read more carefully the question, and delete the big headline. I was not asking about Visual Studio formatting... I was asking about the generated client javascript code, what the server side control renders. ... And please remove the link to the totally unrelated other question.