# Visual Studio 2017 formats asp tags to lowercase

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

From some time, in windows 2010. My Visual Studio 2017(with Resharper 2017.2) has started to reformat asp tags into lowercase.

Example:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Tagprefix="telerik" %>
```

becomes

```
<%@ register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>
```

and I can't find a way to make it not do this. I use `Ctrl-k Ctrl-d` to reformat.

I've also tried resetting the Visual Studio settings, turning off Resharper. Nothing seems to work.

I went through the suggestions in [Visual Studio 2008 formats asp tags to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037288/visual-studio-2008-formats-asp-tags-to-lowercase), but they didn't worked because:

> 1. Visual studio is now 2017 (not 2008)
> 2. Windows folder C:\Documents and Settings[username]\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas structure is changed
>      in windows 10
> 3. The .suo files are also situated at some other place. I deleted both but still didnt worked (as suggested in solution).

**EDIT (28-March-18)**

I had to install windows for some reason, and installed `Visual Studio` again (version 15.6.4 Professional 2017). The issue mentioned in this post is no longer happening. But some of my co-workers still have same issue. And I am sure one day I will have this issue back.

Any help will be appreciated.